# How to code the chess stalemate rule ?

Tags: chess

I'm trying to write a chess game and find that I cannot find solutions to find a stalemate situation. I'm trying to google, but can't find anything. Is there a well-known algorithm or something?

Comment: Have a look at the [chessprogramming](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Stalemate) wikispace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your move generator will be one of two different designs;

- either it checks for legality while generating the moves
- or you generate all possible moves and remove those that are illegal afterwards.

The former is better as it doesn't need post-processing.

A stalemate condition is simply one where there are no legal moves and the moving-side's king is **not** in check.  A checkmate condition is one where there are no legal moves but the moving-side's king **is** in check.

In other words if you've figured out how to detect check and checkmate, you've already got everything necessary to detect stalemate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Open-source code with all the rules for the classic Chess game:
https://github.com/cjortegon/basic-chess

You can run the project right after cloning the project (Android, iOS, Desktop and Web), or you can use the main logic, which is here: https://github.com/cjortegon/basic-chess/tree/master/libgdx/core/src/com/mountainreacher/chess/model

I based my solution on a 3-moments algorithm, first moment is when the player selects a piece from the board, then when the destination of this piece has been chosen and finally when the piece reaches that position (considering that it is an animated game, if not, you can merge step 2 and 3).

The following code has been implemented in Java. From the properties of the model class:

```
boolean turn;
GenericPiece selected, conquest;
ClassicBoard board;
List<int[]> possibleMovements;
int checkType;
```

The first method will handle moments 1, 2 and the special 'conquest' moment (applied to pawn piece only):

```
public boolean onCellClick(int row, int column) {
    if (row == -1 && conquest != null) {
        checkType = 0;
        conquest.changeFigure(column);
        return true;
    } else if (selected != null) {
        if (possibleMovements != null) {
            for (int[] move : possibleMovements) {
                if (move[0] == row && move[1] == column) {
                    // Move the PieceActor to the desired position
                    if (selected.moveTo(row, column)) {
                        turn = !turn;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        selected = null;
        possibleMovements = null;
        return true;
    } else {
        selected = board.getSelected(turn ? Piece.WHITE_TEAM : Piece.BLACK_TEAM, row, column);
        if (selected != null) {
            possibleMovements = new ArrayList<>();
            possibleMovements.addAll(((GenericPiece) selected).getMoves(board, false));
            // Checking the movements
            board.checkPossibleMovements(selected, possibleMovements);
            if (possibleMovements.size() == 0) {
                possibleMovements = null;
                selected = null;
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the following method will handle the 3rd moment (when animation finishes):

```
public void movedPiece(Piece piece) {
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "movedPiece(" + piece.getType() + ")");

    // Killing the enemy
    Piece killed = board.getSelectedNotInTeam(piece.getTeam(),
            piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn());
    if (killed != null) {
        killed.setAvailable(false);
    }

    // Checking hacks
    GenericPiece[] threat = board.kingIsInDanger();
    if (threat != null) {
        checkType = board.hasAvailableMoves(threat[0].getTeam()) ? CHECK : CHECK_MATE;
    } else {
        checkType = NO_CHECK;
    }

    // Checking castling
    if (piece.getFigure() == Piece.ROOK && ((GenericPiece) piece).getMovesCount() == 1) {
        Piece king = board.getSelected(piece.getTeam(),
                piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() + 1);
        if (king != null && king.getFigure() == Piece.KING && ((GenericPiece) king).getMovesCount() == 0) {
            // Left Rook
            if (board.getSelected(piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() - 1) == null) {
                king.moveTo(piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            king = board.getSelected(piece.getTeam(),
                    piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() - 1);
            if (king != null && king.getFigure() == Piece.KING && ((GenericPiece) king).getMovesCount() == 0) {
                // Right Rook
                if (board.getSelected(piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() + 1) == null) {
                    king.moveTo(piece.getRow(), piece.getColumn() + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Conquest
    else if (piece.getFigure() == Piece.PAWN && (piece.getRow() == 0 || piece.getRow() == board.getRows() - 1)) {
        conquest = (GenericPiece) piece;
        checkType = CONQUEST;
    }
}
```

That code covers all the rules from the classic chess, including: regular piece movements, castling, check, check-mate and conquests of pawns.

Comment: These are good links but, as a rule, an answer should be reasonably self-contained. Links move and expire, but these answers are here for... well, a Really Long Time.

Comment: @DavidLively I have included the essential parts of the code from the Github repository.